# Does referencing array index creates a memory leak?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I am reading "Item 6: Eliminate obsolete object references" of Effective Java second edition.

Below is the code snippet.

```
//Can you spot the "memory leak"?
public class Stack {
    private Object[] elements;
    private int size = 0;
    private static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;

    public Stack() {
        elements = new Object[DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY];
    }

    public void push(Object e) {
        ensureCapacity();
        elements[size++] = e;
    }

    public Object pop() {
        if (size == 0)
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        return elements[--size];
    }

    /**
     * Ensure space for at least one more element, roughly doubling the capacity
     * each time the array needs to grow.
     */
    private void ensureCapacity() {
        if (elements.length == size)
            elements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, 2 * size + 1);
    }
}
```

As per this item, memory leak is because after `pop`ping, array index was not referenced to NULL like below:

```
public Object pop() {
    if (size == 0)
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    Object result = elements[--size];
    elements[size] = null; // Eliminate obsolete reference
    return result;
}
```

My understanding have been that suppose for an given array, I have done `elements[0] = new Object()` and then I do this again `elements[0] = new Object()` then my first object would be eligible for garbage collection because 0th index of my array is no more pointing to it.

Is my understanding incorrect? If it is correct then how it is shown as memory leak in Effective Java.

Comment: The stack example is different because the idea is to remove object references from _unused_ indexes that can no longer be accessed. If you just reassign an object to an index that's still accessible, GC will take care of the previous object eventually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got most of it.

If you do:

```
elements[0] = someOtherObject;
```

then the *other* element stored at index 0 is no longer referenced and might be collected.

But the first `pop()` implementation **keeps** that reference in place - it only decreases the "counter" of stored elements. Therefore that object is still referenced - and won't be collected **until** a new object is added to the stack!

As the comment in the second version of `pop()` clearly states - the reference has to be *eliminated* to ensure that the stack doesn't keep a reference to that very object. The object is supposed to be popped - so the stack should not keep knowledge about that *removed* object!

And to confirm the commit: yes, when one pushes *n* object, then pushes *n* other objects, then you don't have a memory leak - because the underlying array references will all be updated and point to new objects then. And yes, if less than *n* objects get pushed after popping, stale references are kept and preventing garbage collection here.

Comment: Thank you for your time to answer. Ok, got it. Could you please confirm my below 2 understanding - I pushed 5 elements to that array (array size is 5 now), then I did pop 5 times (array size is 0 now), now again I pushed 5 elements, now in the end I have no memory leak because all 5 indexes are re-referenced to some other object, right? Memory leak will only be there if suppose I push 10K elements, pop 9K (maybe one by one or all together) and again push 1K elements, then there will be memory leak of 8K object, right?

Comment: @pjj You are welcome. And you are correct - see the updates to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from Effective Java (emphasis mine)

> If a stack grows and then shrinks, the objects that were popped off the stack will not be garbage collected, even if the program using the stack has no more references to them. This is because the stack maintains obsolete references to these objects. An obsolete reference is simply a reference that will never be dereferenced again. In this case, any references outside of the “active portion” of the element array are obsolete. **The active portion consists of the elements whose index is less than size.**

He refers to the references of the elements that are popped off.

But, you are right in your example, when you store the reference to a **new Object** at index 0, there is no reference to the first Object and hence it is eligible for Garbage creation.

But say,

1. You create five Objects (`elements[0]... elements[4]`)
2. You pop three elements. This would leave your `top` variable (`size` here) pointing at index 2.

But still, you would have 5 active references which would prevent the last three objects from being garbage collected.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue pertains to the fact that the array is still holding reference to objects which have only been logically popped off the array(decreasing the size counter). This means that the only way to ever get this memory back would be to garbage collect the entire stack by setting it to null.

You are correct with your case that if you just re-assigned to the nth index it would not be a leak, because you still expect that object to exist. However with pop, your aim is to decrease the size of the stack, which means any memory which was assigned for the top of the stack, should be collected after popping.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The term "Memory Leak" was borrowed from C and is often misused in Java. Memory Leak in C sense is a range of bytes allocated on heap that has no references in the code and thus can't be freed. For example:

```
// ...
char* leak = malloc(10); // Local reference to heap
return;                  // reference lost
```

In Java such leaks are impossible, since any lost reference is subject to GC.
There are situations, however, that can result in Java code using more memory than it should. Your code represents one of many possible examples of such behavior. In your case, as it was explained in previous answers, some elements of the stack will remain in the heap just because the array is holding references  to objects that are no longer needed. In GC environments this is usually called "Lingering objects". A good way to spot memory usage problems in Java is to check heap in use after GC. If heap usage after GC is consistently going up, you probably have lingering objects or other memory allocation problems. For example, if heap in use is 1M after 1st GC, 2M after 2nd GC and 3M after 3d GC - you should probably use a Java Memory Profiler to pinpoint the problem. Note that in your example heap usage will not go up between GCs, but it will not go down either. If you assign null to unused objects, the heap usage will go down after GC if the stack shrinks.